# Can't access array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I use the following code:

```
function Cal() {
    this.currectnum =[5];
    this.bool_num = false;
    this.C=C;
    this.alltimetext = new toString;
    this.addnum = addnum;
    this.equel = equel;

function C() {
    update(0);
    this.bool_num= true;
    this.alltimetext="0";
    console.log(this.currectnum);
}

function update(value) {
    cur = document.getElementById("screen_p");
    cur.innerHTML = value;
    console.log(this.currectnum);
}
```

I don't understand why when I press on C my log is:

```
undefined
[5]
```

How come `C()` can "see" the array but `update(value)` can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call "update" inside "C", you do it without ensuring that `this` will have the correct value. Try

```
update.call(this, 0);
```

instead. That will make sure that inside the "update" function the value of `this` is the same as it is inside "C".

When you call a function without any context object, the value of `this` in the function will be either the global context or (in "strict" mode) `undefined`.

Comment: @user3436708 well I tried to explain in the answer. The value of `this` is determined by how a function call is made. When you just call `update(0)`, the value of `this` in that function will be the global object (`window`) or `undefined`. That's just how JavaScript works.